# MongoDB Connection using PHP - Fatal Error

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to connect mongodb using php script, below are the details:

PHP Version 7.2.12

Mongo Version: v3.2.18

[image]

```
Code:
$hostPort = "76.34.28.76:27017/mydb";
  $username = "test";
  $db  = "mydb";
  $p = "test%402018";
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager("mongodb://$username:$p@$hostPort", [
    "connectTimeoutMS" => 2000,
    "socketTimeoutMS"  => 3000,
]);
var_dump($manager);
$filter = array();
$options = [
    'ssl'=>false
];
$query = new MongoDB\Driver\Query($filter, $options);
$cursor = $manager->executeQuery('db.tmp_collection', $query);

foreach ($cursor as $document) {
    var_dump($document);
}
```

While executing the above script I am getting below error:

Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection timeout calling ismaster on '76.34.28.76:27017'] in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php:19 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php(19): MongoDB\Driver\Manager->executeQuery('db.tmp_collection', Object(MongoDB\Driver\Query)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 19

Comment: That IP address is a public IP, which appears to be a residential cable line -- are you sure that's what you want to be using?

Comment: Double check if that server accepts public connections. Try connecting using mongo shell or tool with GUI like Robo 3T.

Comment: I have changed the ip for question as i this platform is public.

Comment: I can access db using robo.